# JavaScript: Why did the optimization for this loop made it slower?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

This following function searches strings recursively inside arrays:

```
function searchStrings(tree, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
    if (_.isArray(tree[i]) || _.isObject(tree[i])) {
      searchStrings(tree[i], callback)
    } else {
      tree[i] = callback(tree[i])
    }
  }
}
```

The arrays look like this:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'header', { level: 1 }, 'Title' ],
  [ 'para', '\'Example\'' ],
  [ 'para', '“Just in vate--hr”' ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', 'this is another and this is another hr' ],
  [ 'para', [ 'em', 'thoer' ], ' thrr nest ', [ 'strong', 'ert' ] ],
  [ 'bulletlist',
    [ 'listitem', 'this is a test' ],
    [ 'listitem', 'another test' ] ] ]
```

Which I'm later using to replace strings:

```
function replaceCharacters(tree, callback) {

  console.time('time')

  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; ++i) {
    if (tree[i][0] === 'para') {
      searchStrings(tree[i], function(str) {
        if (str.match(/"/g)) {
          str = str
            .replace(/"(?=\b|')/g, '“')
            .replace(/"(?!\b|')/g, '”')
        }

        return str
      })
    }
  }

  console.timeEnd('time')
```

I added the `if (str.match(/"/g))` part thinking that if the loop skips the strings with no `"` the code would run faster since `replace` won't have to run for all the strings. But I was wrong. `time` with that if statement is `1ms` and without that if statement is `0ms`:

> alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2k$ ./m2k10.js test.txt time: 1ms
>
> alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2k$ ./m2k10.js test.txt time: 0ms

What's happening here? Is this also true for `if (tree[i][0] === 'para')` ?

Comment: Can you log value of 'tree[i][0]'. I think you will get different results. Why have you started the for loop with i=1 ? and not 0 ?

Comment: @Pratham Because `tree[0]` is `markdown` and I'm not interested in that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the string.

In your case, the string matches the condition in the ifs. This way, you do the "small" comparisons AND the replace. Your optimization will improve the cases where no replaces need to be done.

A correct test would be one where no changes need to be done.
Also I suggest a much "larger" case. In yours the difference tells you nothing since it can have another reason (maybe a process started just then and lowered browser priority for a bit, etc.).